# Using CommonCrypto with an IV but always returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, commoncrypto

I am using the CommonCrypto CCCryptorCreate to decrypt a message. I am using a password and an IV but it always returns nil.

If I use the CCCryptorCreate to decrypt, but don't use an IV on during encryption on the RUBY side and don't use the IV on the obj-c decrypt side then decryption works perfectly and I can see the message.

But if I use an IV on the RUBY and IV on the obj-c side decryption ends with a nil message object.

I am using this [Encrypt in Objective-C / Decrypt in Ruby using anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260108/encrypt-in-objective-c-decrypt-in-ruby-using-anything)

OBJ-C method:

```
    - (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                         key: (id) key      // data or string
                        initializationVector: (id) iv       // data or string
                                     options: (CCOptions) options
                                       error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
    {
        CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
        CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

        NSParameterAssert([key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);
        NSParameterAssert(iv == nil || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);

        NSMutableData * keyData, * ivData;
        if ( [key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] )
            keyData = (NSMutableData *) [key mutableCopy];
        else
            keyData = [[key dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

        if ( [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
            ivData = [[iv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
        else
            ivData = (NSMutableData *) [iv mutableCopy];    // data or nil

        #if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
            [keyData autorelease];
            [ivData autorelease];
        #endif

        // ensure correct lengths for key and iv data, based on algorithms
        FixKeyLengths( algorithm, keyData, ivData );

        status = CCCryptorCreate( kCCDecrypt, algorithm, options,
                               [keyData bytes], [keyData length], [ivData bytes],
                               &cryptor );

        if ( status != kCCSuccess )
        {
            if ( error != NULL )
                *error = status;
            return ( nil );
        }

        NSData * result = [self _runCryptor: cryptor result: &status];
        if ( (result == nil) && (error != NULL) )
            *error = status;

        CCCryptorRelease( cryptor );

        return ( result );
    }




=== DOES NOT WORK ====
NSData * result = [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmAES128
                                                key: [[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] SHA256Hash]
                               initializationVector: [anIV dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                            options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                              error: &status];


=== DOES WORK ===
NSData * result = [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmAES128
                                                key: [[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] SHA256Hash]
                               initializationVector: nil
                                            options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                              error: &status];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the iv may be different, ensure that the data bytes are the same and the length is correct.

You want `CCCrypt` to do one-shot encryption.

From Apple: `CCCrypt` is a Stateless, one-shot encrypt or decrypt operation. This basically performs a sequence of `CCCrytorCreate()`, `CCCryptorUpdate()`, `CCCryptorFinal()`, and `CCCryptorRelease()`.

Since you are not using `CCCrypt` then you will have to at least add `CCCryptorFinal()` to your example.

Also note that the key and iv really need to be exactly the correct size in bytes. Using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` may not produce the number of bytes expected if there are some characters that require multiple byte encodings. Note: "i" can be encoded as a surrogate pair.

Do not use a password string without using `PBKDF2` to generate a good key.

Consider using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) unless you really know what you are doing with crypto.

Here is **simple example** code of a one-shot encrypt/decrypy method
The key and iv must be exactly the required length.
Any encoding (Base64, NSString, etc) is done outside of this method.

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt // kCCEncrypt or kCCDecrypt
               error:(NSError **)error
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       symmetricKey.bytes, 
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes,
                       dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes,
                       dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError"
                                         code:ccStatus
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        dataOut = nil;
    }

    return dataOut;
}
```

Comment: Tried RNCryptor, but it doesn't work either. The issue is I have no control over what comes from the API we are using. They encrypt the data, pass over an iv, salt and password. RNCryptor seems to have issues with how they are encrypting it on the API side.

Comment: None of the decryptor in RNCryptor accept an IV as a parameter?

Comment: This sample is based on kCCOptionPKCS7Padding. I've tried changing it to kccmodecbc (as used in the recipient) but no has no luck. [Here's the complete situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645749/php-aes256-encryption-compatibility-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Cunning CBC mode is the default. I will look at your question.